# The offending widget is: Uploader Build functions must never return null

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-dependencies

What I am trying to do isto pick images from gallery/camera and then store it in firebase storage.
After clicking on camera/gallery, I can choose the image, but when i try to upload it, then the error below is shown. its shown also in the screen of the emulator.
The error and the code are below.

The error :

```
The following assertion was thrown building Uploader(dirty, state: _UploaderState#8962b):
A build function returned null.

The offending widget is: Uploader
Build functions must never return null.

To return an empty space that causes the building widget to fill available room, return "Container()". To return an empty space that takes as little room as possible, return "Container(width: 0.0, height: 0.0)".

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Uploader file:///Users/yassinezagliz/AndroidStudioProjects/dekra/lib/screens/auth/widgets/box.dart:94:13
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      debugWidgetBuilderValue.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/debug.dart:302:7)
#1      debugWidgetBuilderValue (package:flutter/src/widgets/debug.dart:323:4)
#2      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4632:7)
#3      StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4800:11)
#4      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4343:5)
```

My code is:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';
import 'package:image_cropper/image_cropper.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';


class Box extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BoxState createState() => _BoxState();

}

class _BoxState extends State<Box>{

  File _imageFile;


//Select an image via gallery or camera
  Future<void> _pickImage(ImageSource source) async {
    // ignore: deprecated_member_use
    File selected = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: source);

    setState(() {
      _imageFile = selected;
    });
  }

//Remove image
  void _clear() {
    setState(() => _imageFile = null);
  }

  //Crop Image
  Future<void> _cropImage() async {
    File cropped = await ImageCropper.cropImage(
      sourcePath: _imageFile.path,
      //toolbarColor: Colors.purple,
      //toolbarWidgetColor: Colors.white,
      //toolbarTitle: 'Crop It'
    );

    setState(() {
      _imageFile = cropped ?? _imageFile;
    });
  }



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.pink.shade100,
      appBar: new AppBar(
      title:  new Text("Box Photos"),
      backgroundColor: Colors.pink.shade100,
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.photo_camera),
              onPressed: () => _pickImage(ImageSource.camera),
            ),

            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.photo_library),
              onPressed: () => _pickImage(ImageSource.gallery),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),

      body: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          if (_imageFile != null) ...[
            Image.file(_imageFile),

            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                FlatButton(
                    onPressed: _cropImage,
                    child: Icon(Icons.crop)
                ),
                FlatButton(
                    onPressed: _clear,
                    child: Icon(Icons.refresh)
                ),
              ],
            ),
```

The line which is picked by the exception: Uploader(file: _imageFile) => box.dart:94:13

```
            Uploader(file: _imageFile)
          ]
        ],
      ),
    );


  }

}

class Uploader extends StatefulWidget {

  final File file;

  Uploader({Key key, this.file}) : super(key: key);
  createState() => _UploaderState();
}

class _UploaderState extends State<Uploader> {

  final FirebaseStorage _storage =
  // ignore: deprecated_member_use
  FirebaseStorage(storageBucket: 'gs://dekra-c50a1.appspot.com');

  UploadTask _uploadTask;

  void _startUpload() {
    String filePath = 'images/${DateTime.now()}.png';

    setState(() {
      _uploadTask = _storage.ref().child(filePath).putFile(widget.file);
    });
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Per the error message seems to me that the problem is that your `build` method of `_UploaderState` is not returning a widget. You should at least return an empty Container:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Container();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. In fact that was a part of the issue. I left it empty while I need to put some code inside. thanks again